# Comparing dates isn't working as expected

Tags: datetime, python-3.6, python-3.7

I'm creating an if statement with the following condition:
if date_today >= expiredate:
The expiredate is an output from the dict in string format.
I tried to format it to the datetime so i can check if it is greater then or equal to today:

```
import datetime
from datetime

date_today = datetime.date.today()

for list in dict: # Getting the data out of a list of dicts    
    expiringdate = list.get('expiredate')  # Retrieving the expiredate strings.
    expiredate = datetime.datetime.strftime(expiringdate, '%Y-%m-%d') # Setting the expiredate variable to a datetime format. 
    if date_today >= expiredate:  # Checking if the date is greater then or equal to the other date.
        print('yeah it worked')
    else:
        print('it didn't work')
```

I get the following error.

```
expiredate = datetime.datetime.strftime(expiredate, '%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

I just want to check if the date of today is greater than or equal to the expiringdate. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: what is expiringdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `expiredate` is a string you need to use strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt.strptime("2019-07-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much. I used strftime, but i needed to use strptime.